# Select only half the records

Tags: t-sql

I am trying to figure out how to select half the records where an ID is null. I want half because I am going to use that result set to update another ID field. Then I am going to update the rest with another value for that ID field.

So essentially I want to update half the records someFieldID with one number and the rest with another number splitting the update basically between two values for someFieldID the field I want to update.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In oracle you can use the ROWNUM psuedocolumn.  I believe in sql server you can use TOP.
Example:

```
select TOP 50 PERCENT * from table
```

Comment: Is there sort of a bottom 50 percent?  such as lets say you have 100 records, bottom would be last 50?

Answer (score 9):

You can select by percent:

```
 SELECT TOP 50 PERCENT *fields* FROM YourTable WHERE ...
```

Answer (score 4):

```
update x set id=@value from (select top 50 percent * from table where id is null) x
```

Answer (score 1):

The following SQL will return the col_ids of the first half of the table.

```
SELECT col_id FROM table
WHERE rownum <= (SELECT count(col_id)/2 FROM table);
```

If the total number of col_ids is an odd number then you will get the first half - 1.  This is because, for instance, we have 51 total records, the count(col_id)/2 returns 25.5, and since there is no rownum equal to this result, we get everything equal to 25 and below.  That means the other 26 are not returned.

However, I have not seen the reverse statement working:

```
SELECT col_id FROM table
WHERE rownum > (SELECT count(col_id)/2 FROM table);
```

So if you want the other half of the table, you could just store the first results into a temp table, lets call it TABLE_A. Then just do MINUS on the original table from this table:

`SELECT col_id FROM table`
MINUS
`SELECT col_id FROM table_a`

Hopefully this helps someone.