# Passing value to LIMIT function using SELECT query

Tags: mysql, sql

There is a table named STATION.

I want to display  **half**  rows of the table.

**MYSQL query**

```
SELECT *
FROM STATION
LIMIT (SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM STATION)/2
```

I tried to perform a query like this but I am getting syntax error.

What is wrong in this query?

How can I perform this query?

Comment: 'LIMIT takes one or two numeric arguments, which must both be nonnegative integer constants, '. - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html You might be able to use dynamic sql.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Select only half the records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686648/select-only-half-the-records)

Comment: @Seth - link is for tsql which is not the same as mysql and won't work in mysql..

Answer (score 1):

One method is to use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             ntile(2) over (order by id) as tile
      from t
     ) t
where tile = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have never seen a need of querying exactly half the table.
If you are asking this out of curiosity, that's fair but if there is really a need where you are trying to implement something like this, please revisit the design.

Coming to your question, you can possibly do two things:

1. Implement a stored procedure and query the count and store in a variable and then pass it on to the actual SELECT query for the LIMIT clause.
2. From your client code fire 2 different queries - 1 for count and calculate half (non fraction) and then pass it to the limit clause of next select query .

Comment: 'LIMIT takes one or two numeric arguments, which must both be nonnegative integer constants, '. - dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html

Comment: Yes, it does. In my response the core idea is to calculate the table length (rows) by first query and store it in a variable and then use that (after dividing by 2) in the LIMIT clause of the actual SELECT query.

Comment: Which bit of 'nonnegative integer constants' do you think is incorrect? Please illustrate your answer with code and/or a fiddle.

Comment: I never meant that your response is incorrect in any format in my answer. I just described the process in which the original goal of the question can be achieved. At the core - it will need 2 queries and not 1 which the original problem was all about.